# Mix of power supplies

Tags: power-supply, basic

I am struggling to understand what happens when two power supplies are connected:

[image]

Both supplies build a whole circuit, the rest of the second supply is left out for simplification
Both power supplies are typically DC laboratory ones.

In the upper case: what happens between the two grounds of the two supplies?

In the bottom case: people say that as the two grounds are connected to each other the potential is shared. But in reality there is a small resistance. But what does physically really happens as the two supplies are different energy systems and why is the ground potential as a result equally?

Comment: It depends on your power supplies. They could be completely standalone and isolated, like if you think about batteries. They could also be two power supplies with common reference, like for example take two desktop computers which both have their common terminals connected together through mains earth wire. So it's unknown what kind of power supplies you mean.

Comment: what do you mean with "grounds"? there's no ground anywhere in your circuit.

Comment: In the top case the second power supply isn't connected to anything, so you can ignore it. In the bottom unless the power supplies have identical output voltages they will pump current into one another to try and force each other to a common voltage. Possibly one or both will burn out.

Comment: The question is updated.

Comment: You might be confusing "ground" with "power-supply negative". They're not always the same thing. We show "ground" by adding a GND symbol to the schematic at a certain point. We can then reference all voltage readings to that point for convenience. (This would be similar to taking sea-level as a reference and all heights and depths can be relative to that. Of course, I could use my front door step as "ground" and take all altitude references from there.)